Cloudflare tunnel can't access my Docker compose containers
Tunneling only works with containers but not with docker-compose containers
Hello everyone,
I’ve successfully set up a Cloudflare tunnel with containers on my local Docker Desktop. However, I’m facing an issue when trying to connect the same tunnel to a container running via Docker Compose (which uses a custom network). The tunnel is "running", but I’m unable to access my domain.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
